# Attach ssh command output to a file descriptor

Tags: bash

So i am trying to have the output of my ssh command consumed at different points in time and potentially within a subshell as well. I tried with fifos and with exec like:

```
exec 10< <(ssh host 'i=0;while :;do ((i++));echo $i;done')

read a <&10
echo $a
read a <&10
echo $a
```

the output i am looking is: 1 and 2. currently i get 1 and 1, a new process starts every time i read from the fd 10. Same thing with fifo.
Any ideas of how to sort this out?

---

EDIT: I restarted my pc and the problem disappeared. It might had been yet another issue with wsl2

Comment: Your script as-is works as intended for me: I get `1` and `2`. However, you might try `read -u 10 a` instead of redirecting.

Comment: it looks like it was a wsl2 issue (not the first I had so far), I restarted my pc and it worked...